# CORS Error happens only on Mac and only on certain routes

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I am experiencing CORS errors just on a MAC and just for certain routes. E.g. this route is failing:

[image: failed-cors]

and this route is succeeding:

[image: success-cors]

I included cors like this in my code:

```js
import express from "express";

const app = express();

app
  .options("*", cors())
  .use(cors())

// More code

export default app
```

Any idea what could cause this and how to fix it?

Comment: You have a 500 Internal Server Error there, which most likely is what makes it not even get that far that your CORS configuration comes into play. So go check the logs and figure out what caused that 500.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I had the same thought, but the failing route is working fine in a different browser on a different operating system...

Comment: Well if you're happy enough with simply telling your users that they should use a different browser, you can leave it at that. But if not ... well then you need to investigate the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This was caused by NordVPN Anti Virus Software blocking my domain... Maybe this helps someone in the future.